# Appstore application to assassinate anyone

Tags: society, alternate-worlds, alternate-reality, internet

Being the pessimistic person  I am who always looks at the dark side of life, mostly because in this world only a small percentage of humans enjoy the luck and luxury of living in the light side of life, I came up with an idea for my world based on the events that made me lose my job.

Today it's seems that applications are slowly and silently stealing jobs from experienced and licensed experts, in a way making the skill in marketing oneself more important than the actual skills in the needed job.
But that's just fine, another opportunity for me to make the inhabitants of my world suffer and suffocate in their own despair as they scream ''Why god!? Why!?'' while staring at the sky with the eyes of a poor bastard who's about to die.

Do you remember that period of time when the internet believed the ''dark web'' or ''deep web'' was some kind of nest for the sick and depraved where anyone could smuggle child porn, weapons, drugs and enrol themselves as private hackers and assassins or even sell slaves?

Except that thing died the moment it started because there's no incognito mode for payments online... any kind of wacky crypto coin or online payment method is public, the blockchain is literally public and anyone can see what any stranger on the internet is doing with their money, and anyone buying something illegal on the internet is not gonna enjoy it for long. So criminals have to get cash payments if they wanna keep their business otherwise they will run out of clients, and eventually, they will meet an undercover policeman when getting out of their nest to get paid....wack. Why? Because the ''dark web'' is free for anyone so when Cr1minalGuy123 posts their advertisement for hitman services anyone can see it, even another crazier and more violent guy or a policemen... so assassins can at worst end up meeting each other killing one another and at best hope for a few years in prison.
But here's the thing, I want this conspiracy to be true. I want this world to have a viable and public application where anyone of any age and gender or nation can pay for someone to be killed.

Think of it like uberdrive or ubereats but now you pay someone to kill that girl who played you back in high school 8 years ago and left you traumatized and transformed into an incel.

So the question would then be **how to make payments safe and private for clients and assassins?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126539/discussion-on-question-by-cecilia-appstore-application-to-assassinate-anyone).

Comment: There are patents being filed to try to design anonymous digital payments. Don't remember the details - just that I've seen articles in the payments trade magazines on that topic.

Answer (score 3):

**No hitman will use this app.**

A hitman costs about [5,000 to 100,000 USD](https://www.quora.com/How-much-does-it-cost-to-hire-a-contract-killer-Within-black-markets-what-is-the-going-rate-on-a-strategic-assassination#:%7E:text=It%20depends%20on%20the%20country%20and%20the%20type%20of%20hitman.&text=In%20countries%20like%20USA%20and,%24100000%20%2C%20depending%20on%20the%20hitman.). The cost of getting caught for a hitman is 25 to life for murder. Therefore there is no such thing as a sloppy hitman. A professional hitman needs to know who is hiring them to get payment for the job, or take the payment early and just not do the hit. A professional needs to be anonymous also but has methods of remaining anonymous. Furthermore, these methods vary and make each hitman hard to contact in a different way, ensuring that contract killers are harder to track down.

**Single point of failure.**

The app on the other hand is a single point of failure for a hitman. Sure, the company will swear that they won't expose the hitmen to the government, but then the government hits them with Mass Conspiracy to Murder they might change their minds. Even if the government doesn't shut it down they can still exploit the app and monitor traffic to determine who is contacting who and determine who the contract killers are.

**Why selling murder is not the same as selling cars.**

The difficulty people have contacting contract killers is partly by the government's design and partly by the contract killers' design. If contacting a contract killer is easy, then cops would anonymously hound them until they make a mistake. By increasing the cost of even contacting them through secret channels it makes it harder for Governments to root out contract killers, but lets actual costumers through the rigorous process.

**Most likely this is a scam.**

An app that claims to kill someone for $1,000 sounds good. They say you need to use their custom crypto currency to do it, but that is fine. So you put the money in and nothing happens. You try to withdraw it but they block that from happening and have already spent your money. You go to the bank to try and get your money back and the bank asks who you deposited the money with and for what. You then realize that you either have to give up on the money or admit to conspiracy to murder. When the government cracks down on this after someone decided to admit to murder the fraudsters get off with fraud charges instead of murder charges since there was never any intent to commit murder. The company doesn't suffer from bad reputation as hitman services don't operate on word of mouth anyways, or advertising for that matter.

**Cops will love this app.**

Police hate working hard for their charges. Getting arrests with warrants and investigation is difficult. But imagine if there was an app that if you found it on someone's phone would constitute as much probable cause as you want or be straight up convictable. This app constitutes this.

18 U.S. Code § 1117 - Conspiracy to murder

> If two or more persons conspire to violate section 1111, 1114, 1116, or 1119 of this title, and one or more of such persons do any overt act to effect the object of the conspiracy, each shall be punished by imprisonment for any term of years or for life.

If a police officer effect a search of a phone you can be sure that they will check for that app first. If they find the app then they can use that to write up warrants for nearly anything they want. A few of these will eventually lead them to the people running the app and get them shutdown.

Comment: never heard of any professiona hitman outside the CIA

Comment: Professional Hitman just means a guy who has killed for money and plans to do it again. Who did you think would be doing the killing?

Answer (score 1):

**The app has it's own coin**

The app can only thrive if two things are met. Anonymity and secure payment.

The app strips all identity from the source, which is accepted. Payment is done via the account in virtual money. This money can then safely be withdrawn by the assassins. As the app offers many other services, the reason for the money is hidden this way, as you do not know if the money is because someone bought a car from you or to kill someone. This is accepted by all governments as tax free (possibly up to a certain point). This way, anyone can hide why they used the app.

Comment: Good premise, however; how do you earn these coins in the first place (using real money gets us back to the original problem)? The app would need a way to make more coins. Would a government not begin to require the app to hold certain data on it's advertisements? It would have to track the amount of coins each user has and where they've come from, at the very least. As I said, still a good idea but not necessarily water tight - it is an extra step removed though.

Comment: Add a connection to the alternative money transfer system called Hawala. Then, the money can be hidden among many legitimate money transfers.

Answer (score 1):

**I'll propose a physical solution: drop locations**

This has been a feature of black markets since before the internet and is still one of the most secure. The weakness is that the amount cannot be varied once the drop is made. It works better with standardised payments (for example maybe people of different social status might command different bounties based on how much security they are likely to have around them) but it could be that punters set their price and hope to find a provider willing to accept it for the job in question.

A punter deposits a payment in a public location say in an envelope wedged behind a street sign somewhere. All that the app needs to do is use an onion router to connect punters to service providers, when a service provider accepts a contract the punter sends them the location of the payment. Maybe the payments could be 50/50 with one deposit location serving as a downpayment and another serving as the completion payment.

The app could have a feedback feature to tell punters which providers have a good track record of payments not going missing.

Comment: this one does seem to at least decrease the failure rate of aspiring killers by a lil bit, good one.